# How and where to store files uploaded by client locally on the server with Svelte?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, svelte, vite, sveltekit

The app is made with Svelte, SvelteKit on the stack UBUNTU, NodeJs, Nginx.

The users can upload files that may contain confidential data.

It works perfectly in dev but not after deployment in production after a `npm run build`.

My current code contains the relative path `./private/files/products/` but this path does not exist in production in the build folder.

```
await writeFile(`./private/files/products/${fileId}`, file.stream(), function (err) {
    if (err) {}
});
```

The objective is to store the files in the parent folder of the web root, never available to client.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Paths should not be hard coded with Svelte. You have to use environment variables et let Svelte and Vite handle the path.

```
import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';

await writeFile(`${env.PWD}/private/files/products/${fileId}`, file.stream(), function (err) {
    if (err) {}
});
```

You may also [add some environment variables](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#environment-variables) to `.env` files that will then be available through `import { env } from '$env/dynamic/private';`

*Do not forget to create the directories on your production server and apply the appropriate permissions (chown and chmod).*